# How do I read in several lines to the same line?

Tags: c#

Ok, so the title isn't really the best. But here's my problem:

I've made a little program that writes a few names and an integer to a .txt document when certain event occurs from an extern program.

The thing is that a name can show up in several lines in the document, so I want to sumarize the integers for each specific person so that I get the total amount of points for him/her and then sort it.

For example:

The original line:

```
Aaaa Aaa 5
Bbbb Bbb 7
Cccc Ccc 2
Aaaa Aaa 4
Cccc Ccc 4
Bbbb Bbb 1
Dddd Ddd 1
```

The output I want:

```
1. Aaaa Aaa 9
2. Bbbb Bbb 8
3. Cccc Ccc 6
4. Dddd Ddd 1
```

Is there any way to do this in C#?
I've tried to read in every single line in the file and search for the name of a person. But that doesn't really help and I don't know how to solve this.
Any advice?

Comment: Maybe you need a real database for this instead of a file.

Comment: But if I don't have any database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Linq query returns the desired result as `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> lineGroups = File.ReadLines(path)
.Select((l, i) => new { Line = l, Parts = l.Split() })
.Select(x => new
{
    Number = x.Parts.ElementAtOrDefault(2).TryGetInt() ?? 1,
    Col1 = x.Parts.ElementAtOrDefault(0),
    Col2 = x.Parts.ElementAtOrDefault(1),
    x.Line,
    x.Parts
})
.GroupBy(x =>new { x.Col1, x.Col2 })
.Select((g, groupIndex) =>
    string.Format("{0}. {1} {2} {3}",
    groupIndex + 1, g.Key.Col1, g.Key.Col2, g.Sum(x => x.Number)));
```

output:

```
foreach (var grp in lineGroups)
    Console.WriteLine(grp);
```

This is the output:

```
1. Aaaa Aaa 9
2. Bbbb Bbb 8
3. Cccc Ccc 2  // different than your desired ouput but seems to be correct
4. Dddd Ddd 1
```

These are my extension methods that i use in Linq queries to Try-Parse a `string` to common value type like `int`(as above). It return a nullable type if it was not parsable:

```
public static class NumericExtensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this int value, int fromInclusive, int toInclusive)
    {
        return value >= fromInclusive && value <= toInclusive;
    }

    public static Decimal? TryGetDecimal(this string item)
    {
        Decimal d;
        bool success = Decimal.TryParse(item, out d);
        return success ? (Decimal?)d : (Decimal?)null;
    }

    public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
    {
        int i;
        bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
        return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
    }

    public static bool TryGetBool(this string item)
    {
        bool b = false;
        Boolean.TryParse(item, out b);
        return b; ;
    }

    public static Version TryGetVersion(this string item)
    {
        Version v;
        bool success = Version.TryParse(item, out v);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: @OP: Note that someone has edited your question. Now my sample data is different and my comment about the desired/actual output is obsolete.

Comment: I found a problem though, if the names vary by length this won't work.

Comment: @JimmyLindberg: Do you have an example? If the names are different(if the length of a name is different the name itself is different) they should belong to different groups.

Comment: I tried with:
Aaaa Aaaaa 5
Aaaaa Aaa 7
And it returned:
1. Aaaa Aaaaa 5
2. Aaaaa Aaa 7

Comment: @JimmyLindberg: Yes, i've assumed that the first column(separated by a white-space character) is the firstname and the second column in the lastname(or vice-versa). So if the first- or last-name is different two names are different. Was this assumption incorrect?

Comment: I meant that if you had some names like:
Adam Aaronson 5
Kim Sceiffert 7
Dean Martin 4
Eric Nielsen 7
Dean Martin 2
It would sort them. But your solution is great, except that it doesn't work if the names are different in length.

Comment: If you want to sort them you have to insert following before the `.GroupBy`: `.OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @JimmyLindberg: in what way? It'll order by the first column(i assume first-name) and then by the second column(if the first is the same). However, i still don't understand what didn't work for you since the real names you have provided should work without a problem.

Comment: I may have been unclear, but I meant to sort it by the number of points amassed, not the names. Sorry if you've misunderstood this.

Comment: @JimmyLindberg: Then use `OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(x => x.Number))`

Comment: Where should I put this line?

Comment: If i replace the original line I get this error "Error 1 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Now you have to remove my last orderby and add this orderby after the GroupBy because you want to order by the sum of each group. You could also select an anonymous type from the group which contains the number.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the text is somewhat a key you use to sum up the numbers, so why not use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to sum up first and write later?

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> sums = new Dictionary<string, int>();

...

if (sums.ContainsKey(theNewString))
    sums[theNewString] += theNewNumber;
else
    sums[theNewString] = theNewNumber;
```

And when you know you're done, write the file. You can also re-write the file after every update of the dictionary, but please remember that the dictionary will grow and grow if you don't purge it.

Also: This won't work if the program is restarted, unless you create a new file every time the program starts. Otherwise you'd have to read an existing file into the dictionary when the program starts to continue summing up.

Comment: It's just that the first file is already written, so I have to read the file and write to another file after I've sorted and sumarazied the values.

Comment: You could also write to the same file. You could also - when a new value is coming in - read the file into a dictionary, change the dictionary (summing up maybe) and then write the dictionary to the file again.

Comment: Ok, It's just that I don't know how to read in duplicates when I use the ReadLine or ReadToEnd-functions.
Is there some kind of FindDuplicates implemented in C#?

Comment: If you wrote the file using the "dictionary method", there won't be any duplicates in the first place. Even if there were, you could use the above code to handle these, too. Read a line, split it into key and value and check whether the dictionary already contains the key. If so, sum up, otherwise create new entry

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary with the keys as the names. As value of each item in the dictionary, use the integer and add it to (the value of) an already existing key (or not).

Comment: It's just that the names are random and that the file is already written from another program.

Comment: You can read the file and keep the dictionary in memory ... if you need a new file to output, then you need to write some code to write the dictionary info to a (different or not) file.

Answer (score 2):

```
lines.GroupBy(line => string.Join(" ", line.Split().Take(2)))
     .Select((g, index) => 
           string.Format("{0}. {1} {2}", 
            index, 
            g.Key, 
            g.Sum(line => int.Parse(line.Split().Last()))));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Split())
    .GroupBy(y => new { y1 = y[0], y2 = y[1] })
    .Select(g => new { g.Key.y1, g.Key.y2, Sum = g.Sum(v => int.Parse(v[2])) })
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Sum)
    .Select(m => m.y1 + " " + m.y2 + " " + m.Sum).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that (not so elegant, but not dependant on the number of spaces)

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"<pathToFile>");

var result = lines
                .Select(m => m.Split(' '))
                .Select(x => new {
                    text = string.Join(" ", x.Where(z => z != x.Last())),
                    val = Convert.ToInt32(x.Last())
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.text)
                .Select(g => new {
                    text =g.Key,
                    sum = g.Sum(z => z.val)
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution with LINQ and regular expressions (for verifying line format and getting names and values from it):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?<name>.*)\s(?<value>\d+)$");

var query = from line in File.ReadLines(file_name)
            let match = regex.Match(line)
            where match.Success
            select new {
                Name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
                Value = match.Groups["value"].Value
            } into item
            group item by item.Name into g
            orderby g.Key
            select new {
                Name = g.Key,
                Total = g.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Value))
            };
```

Value overflow is not verified here. If it is possible that some values are bigger than Int32.MaxValue, then change sum calculation to

```
g.Sum(x => { int value; return Int32.TryParse(x.Value, out value) ? value : 0; })
```